# How to fix "failed to create template" when creating new dotnet project?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to write my fist console app walking through this tutorial :
https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/dotnet/hello-world-tutorial/install

after installing .NET sdk and opening a new command prompt and running the following command:dotnet
everything went smoothly but after entering this command:

```
dotnet new console -o MyApp -f net6.0
```

this error showed up

[image]

any solutions?

Comment: did you install the sdk or just the runtime? check `dotnet --info`

Comment: should have read the error message, sorry | 1. open the windows explorer navigate to the location you want your console app to be 2. in the address bar type "cmd" this will open the console with with the path set to the current location of the explorer 3. type your command again

Comment: As you may find here: https://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/command-prompt-window-in-file-explorer-windows-10 | first google search result, about opening cmd

Comment: As a side not, I love that the block `Got an error?` on https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/dotnet/hello-world-tutorial/create which covers your error, has a link to Stack Overflow if the SDK wasn't found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer here should be easy. You are inside the System32 folder in Windows, which is critical and normally you do not have Writing Permissions in there, because it is VERY critical to the windows operating System and you should store your projects in another folder.

Maybe try another folder, like Documents or something like that, or is there a reason you want to do that there?

You can read through the forum at [This Link](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/write-permission-in-system32-folder/a15824e2-8545-4a93-b1d0-1f0110c28c32), if you want to know more about it. There also stands, how you can access this specific folder if you really want to. (Which I really do not recommend, unless you really know your stuff)